# Why can't my friend function access the private members?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The addBudget function in AuxiliaryOffice class is a friend function of the budget class. But the compiler is giving me error, that it cannot access the private members of the Budget class.

```
class Budget;
class AuxiliaryOffice
{
private:
    double auxBudget;
public:
    AuxiliaryOffice()
    {
        auxBudget = 0;
    }
    double getDivisionBudget()
    {
        return auxBudget;
    }
    void addBudget(double a, Budget &ref)
    {
        ref.corpBudget += a;
        auxBudget += a;
    }
};
class Budget
{
private:
    static double corpBudget;
    double divisionBudget;
    friend void AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget(double, Budget&);
public:
    Budget()
    {
        divisionBudget = 0;
    }
    void addBudget(double a)
    {
        corpBudget += a;
        divisionBudget += a;
    }
    double getDivisionBudget() const
    {
        return divisionBudget;
    }
    double getCorpBudget() const
    {
        return corpBudget;
    }
};
double Budget::corpBudget = 0;
```

Comment: A computer tries to compile your program from start to finish. It reads it from the beginning to the end, and not the other way around. At the point where your computer read `AuxiliaryOffice` and tries to compile it, it has no idea, whatsoever, what this mysterious `Budget` class is, which was only forward-declared at that point. It's a big mystery to your compiler, and so your compiler is very unhappy about trying to access the members of methods of an undefined class.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is stopping your code from compile before friendship is even an issue.

You declared Budget as an incomplete type:

```
class Budget;
```

And then wrote code that calls functions on it, before the class is defined.  That is not allowed.  You have to declare functions that use it, but NOT define it until after the class is defined.

That's why (one of the reasons why) we put class declarations in headers, and implementations in .cpp files.  It also reduces coupling between files, and can help with build speeds.

Here's a compacted version of your code that compiles, with most of the unessential lines removed (as you should aim to do in future questions):

```
class Budget;
class AuxiliaryOffice {
    double auxBudget = 0;

public:
    void addBudget(double a, Budget &ref);
};

class Budget {
    // Unrelated, but useful to know:
    // inline statics can be initialized in the class like this, no
    // definition necessary in the .cpp file.
    inline static double corpBudget = 0; 
    friend void AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget(double, Budget&);
};

// if in .cpp, remove "inline", if in header, keep it
inline void AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget(double a, Budget &ref) {
    ref.corpBudget += a;
}
```

see it live: https://godbolt.org/z/JYDZMz

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not about friendship, is about the order of definition. At the point you've defined `AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget` the definition of `Budget` is incomplete, hence the member `corpBudget` isn't defined yet.

Change it to:

```
class Budget;
class AuxiliaryOffice
{
private:
    double auxBudget;
public:
    AuxiliaryOffice()
    {
    auxBudget = 0;
    }
    double getDivisionBudget()
    {
    return auxBudget;
    }
    void addBudget(double a, Budget &ref);
};


class Budget
{
private:
    static double corpBudget;
    double divisionBudget;
    friend void AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget(double, Budget&);
public:
    Budget()
    {
        divisionBudget = 0;
    }
    void addBudget(double a)
    {
        corpBudget += a;
        divisionBudget += a;
    }
    double getDivisionBudget() const
    {
        return divisionBudget;
    }
    double getCorpBudget() const
    {
        return corpBudget;
    }
};
double Budget::corpBudget = 0;

inline void AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget(double a, Budget &ref)
{
    ref.corpBudget += a;
    auxBudget += a;
}
```

That will work.

Comment: If that definition of `AuxiliaryOffice::addBudget` is in a header file, you'll want to declare it `inline`.

Comment: You went a little overboard, `inline` was only required at the definition not the declaration.